# jQuery TypeError: includes is not a function in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery and I am using

```
$("label").each(function(){

    var labelValue = $(this).text();


    if(labelValue.includes("*")){

        $(this).addClass("required");

        $(this).text(labelValue.replace("*",""));

    }

});
```

I am finding  label which is using *  and replace to blank.this process working

Properly in google chrome but giving error in **Firefox**

```
TypeError: labelValue.includes is not a function 

if(labelValue.includes("*")){
```

How to resolve this error.

Comment: Possible Dup of [includes() not working in all browsers](//stackoverflow.com/q/31340868)

Comment: @Tushar any other solution full fill this requirement

Comment: @Tushar https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: you can use `indexOf()` instead

Comment: @ShahzadDitro You can use `indexOf` or polyfill provided by MDN. Check the answer on dupe.

Comment: `includes` is working maybe you have a type in your code https://jsfiddle.net/mbe7mkee/

Comment: you can use `indexOf()` or `match` with regular expression for better support across all browsers.

Comment: @julekgwa It is working for you because you're using latest browser that support this method. OP might be using old version of browser.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: if you just need to loop through labels which there text `contains *` .. I prefer to use the selector `$("label:contains('*')").each(function(){ }` instead of using if statement .. But with if statement you need to use MohitBhardwaj solution

Comment: my problem has been resolved using @Mohit Bhardwaj or Tushar solution